# PyBrain: overflow encountered in square, invalid value encountered in multiply

Tags: python, pybrain

I create a neural network like this:

```
n = FeedForwardNetwork()

inLayer = LinearLayer(43)
bias = BiasUnit()
hiddenLayer = SigmoidLayer(100)
outLayer = LinearLayer(1)

n.addInputModule(inLayer)
n.addModule(bias)
n.addModule(hiddenLayer)
n.addOutputModule(outLayer)

in_to_hidden = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer)
bias_to_hidden = FullConnection(bias, hiddenLayer)
hidden_to_out = FullConnection(hiddenLayer, outLayer)

n.addConnection(in_to_hidden)
n.addConnection(bias_to_hidden)
n.addConnection(hidden_to_out)

n.sortModules()
```

I train it the following way (I'm simplifying, it's being trained in multiple iterations):

```
self.trainer = BackpropTrainer(self.neural_net, learningrate=0.8)
(...)
ds = SupervisedDataSet(self.net_input_size, 1)
ds.addSample([...], np.float64(learned_value))
(...)
self.trainer.trainOnDataset(ds)
```

Sometimes I get the following warnings:

> (...)/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py3.5.egg/pybrain/supervised/trainers/backprop.py:99: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
>     error += 0.5 * sum(outerr ** 2)
>
> (...)/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py3.5.egg/pybrain/structure/modules/sigmoidlayer.py:14: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
>     inerr[:] = outbuf * (1 - outbuf) * outerr

And then when I check the saved net file I see that *all* weights are `nan`:

```
(...)
<FullConnection class="pybrain.structure.connections.full.FullConnection" name="FullConnection-8">
    <inmod val="BiasUnit-5"/>
    <outmod val="SigmoidLayer-11"/>
    <Parameters>[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]</Parameters>
</FullConnection>
(...)
```

Comment: You're learning rate is far too high. Normal rates (based on the problem) are something like 0.01 or 0.001 e.g. If you're learning rate is so high and especially if you're training a huge amount of epochs your weights can get too high, hence diverging into NaN values.

Comment: @ascenator But the problem occures only at the beginning (let's say first 20 or 30 epochs) - never later.

Comment: @ascenator You might be right. I did a couple of tests with training rate at 0.1 and haven't seen any warnings.

Comment: @ascenator I think you can safely put it as an answer. There are also other possible causes: https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/issues/98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, here comes an answer:

Having a learning rate of 0.8 is ineffective since it *can* lead to errors like yours and prevent effective learning of the network.

With such a high learning rate, based on your cost function, the network could easily change your weights by very large amounts, therefore the weights might overflow into NaN values.

Generally (even if your weights do not overflow into NaN values) a high learning rate is not a good idea in terms of learning, too. You're network solves specific problems by learning from a large training data set. If you're learning rate is very high, like 0.8, the network adapts **very** hard to the current epoch's data.
Most of the information / learned features of former epoch's will be completely lost, because the network adjusts itself strongly to the current epoch's error rate.

For most problems typical learning rates are something like 0.01 or 0.001 or even less because you want to draw small conclusion from one single epoch and rather learn invariant features of several epochs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to guess with arbitrary numbers! In a feed forward network, you'll be wasting your time with anything more than a learning rate of 1/n, where n is the number of neurons in your network. If you build a learning rate that reduces over training steps, you'll more easily resolve subtle relationships, but it'll take considerably longer per degree (if you will) of subtlety, since only some diminishing fraction of the entirety of the network's state will be affected per training step.

If your learning rate is in excess of 1/n, the allowed freedom for change in the network as a whole *exceeds* 100% change per each node, which is far more akin to *forgetting* than to remembering.